# Can ZBar scan small QR codes?

Tags: ios, qr-code

I am having trouble reading small QR codes with ZBar under iOS.  It seems I cannot get it to scan in 7mm x 7mm codes.  Is this a configuration issue or a limitation of the ZBar library?  I can scan these codes with other apps like Nanoreader.

Comment: have u resolve this problem??
because now i am facing this problem,can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely yes. You can decode small qrcode with ZBar. You will need get a good image of it (but you will use the live mode), so you can do it.

Comment: I have 7mm x 7mm codes that scan great on my Android devices but don't scan under iOS.

Comment: Post some pictures of a great quality of this small qrcode. The size isn't important, but the quality of how you scan this code is.

Answer (score 0):

I have set the `UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh` value to scan a 15mm x 15mm QR Code successfully

`ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
reader.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;
...`

Comment: Which device were you using?

Comment: @gonzobrains, I had tried it in iPhone5s and iPhone4

Comment: That may explain your success.  I asked this question back when I was working with an iPod3 and an iPhone3GS!